# How to run multiple feature file in behave using pycharm professional

Tags: python, pycharm, gherkin, python-behave

I have created multiple feature file using python language in pycharm professional.

So whenever i try to run multiple feature file simultaneously it shows ConfigError while I'm using tags.

In which way I need to do, to run specific scenarios and multiple feature file in behave using python

**How to set the feature file path or how to change the default feature path?**

[Config error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwGIp.png)

[Default path error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFClb.png)

Comment: When you get the Config error **while running multiple feature file or running a specific scenario under a single feature file.**

Comment: While running specific scenarios.

Comment: From the error message in the screenshot it seems that windows does not pass the argument in single quotes the way you would expect. Try double quotes instead, like this: behave -n "Login functionality"

Comment: With your input, I get the same error as I attached in the screenshot. Do I need to specify the feature file also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Pycharm terminal, you have to change the directory path to your Features folder before proceeding to run a particular scenario. Because it searches the features file under wrong path.

Change your path as mentioned below.

**C:\Users\MSTEMP\PycharmProjects\ORE_DEMO>** *cd mention your path upto features folder*

Once you switched to the Features folder.Use the following commands

**To run a specific scenario:**
*behave -n "scenario name"*

**To run a feature file:**
*behave "feature name.feaure"*

**To run multiple feature file**
behave "*feature name one* **.feature**" "*feature name two* **.feature**"

Comment: My behave command is like this : `behave features/Feature_Login.feature  -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o allure-results  --no-capture --no-capture-stderr -f plain`

How can I run multiple files as per my command. It works fine with single file.